# Use PHP variable defined in parent file in included pattern (WordPress Block Theme)

Tags: theme-development

I am developing a custom Block Theme based off of the Twenty Twenty-Four Theme. It has been a long time since I have developed a custom theme, so Block Themes are new to me. I'm still reluctant to use the Editor to create complex custom Patterns as it seems unwieldy. Anyhow, it seems that I am not understanding how normal PHP variable scope is or is not preserved when using `<!-- wp:pattern -->` markup as opposed to a traditional PHP `include`.

Example:
I have a page containing multiple queries, each with posts from a specific category. The bulk of the code is repeated, so I broke it off into a separate Pattern file. I am declaring a global variable in the 'parent' Pattern file, redefining the variable as needed, and including the 'child' Pattern like so,

```
<?php
global $category_name;
$category_name = '<mycategory>';
?>
<!-- wp:pattern {"slug":"<mynamespace>/<mypattern>"} /-->
```

then in `/patterns/<mypattern>.php`, I am doing,

```
global $category_name;
$posts = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'category_name' => $category_name
    )
);
```

However, the query returns all posts. A simple `echo` of the variable after retrieving with `global` prints nothing. Note that this repeated section of code worked as expected when it was still in the 'parent' file.

Official documentation on Block Theme development is woefully thin, unless I'm missing something.

---

Edit: I ended up using a traditional `include` as I realized that perhaps this is not the intended use for Patterns (I am developing this theme for my own use, not distribution; the contents of the Pattern are repeated code, but not intended for reuse elsewhere on the site). That said, I would like to understand more how PHP variables are accessed (if at all) in Pattern template files.